# MongoDB aggregation, counting each item in array and grouping by item

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

here I have an array of duplicate items like this

```js
[
 'gg',
 'bb',
 'dd',
 'cc',
 'll',
 'aa',
 'cc',
 'gg',
 'bb',
 'dd',
 'cc',
 'bb',
 'dd',
 'll',
 'aa',
]
```

and what I'm willing to return is like this

```js
{
 'gg': 2,
 'bb': 3,
 'dd': 3,
 'cc': 2,
 'll': 2,
 'aa': 2,
}
```

Can it be done with MongoDB aggregation ??? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) as stages of aggregation pipiline:
**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $unwind: "$items"
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$items",
          count: {
            $sum: 1
          }
        }
      }
    ])
```

**Result:**

```
{
    "_id": "ll",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "gg",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "bb",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": "cc",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": "aa",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "dd",
    "count": 3
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

This also works really well...

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$email",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            count: { $gt: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : "a@gmail.com", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "b@gmail.com", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "c@gmaiL.com", "count" : 8 }
{ "_id" : "d@gmail.com", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "e@gmail.com", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "f@gmail.com", "count" : 2 }
```